# Bootstrap: How to put a box over a header image?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to put a text box with a white background over my header image. but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here's my code so far:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img class="img-responsive sofiheaderborder" src="assets/header2.png">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-13 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <ul>
        <li>Text row 1</li>
        <li>Text row 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "_it doesn't work_" isn't much to go on...

Comment: What doesn't work? Please provide as much detail as you can.

Answer (score 0):

A JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/6LyHz/1/

```
.container{
position:relative;
}
.col-lg-3.col-md-13.col-sm-12.col-xs-12{
position:absolute;
top:25px;
left:25px;
background:white;
}
```

Comment: Thx. Worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

You will use the class ' container ' in every page, so i dont recommend altering the container and also those col-md-- things. Instead, give a class name to that div ion which you have text and use -VE margin to pull up. Or, the text-div first and then image, then use margin-top. Any how you have to use z-index. Then you might even test and change in media query also for different screens.
I ll try in jsfiddle and to give you the link soon